# Anonymous type for datarow-object isn't working

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, anonymous-types, datarow

I want to select some fields from a datarow doing something like:

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new { x.Field<string>("Field1"), x.Field<string>("Field2")});
```

Unfortunately this isn't working saying:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

How can I achieve what I want?

**Edit:** As it seems there are (at least) two ways to achieve it:

1. Name 'em:

   ```
   var result = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new 
   { 
       Field1 = x.Field("Field1"), 
       Field2 = x.Field("Field2")
   });
   ```
2. Create a new object

Let's say we have a class

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string field1, string field2)
    {
        this.Field1 = field1;
        this.Field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

we can do the following:

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new MyClass(x.Field<string>("Field1"), x.Field<string>("Field2")));
```

Comment: There was an answer using a tuple, which I prefer because I need to transform the resultset into a class of my own. Unfortunately someone deleted the answer...

Comment: Why would you need a `Tuple` to create a class of your own?

Comment: I've added a tuple example to my answer but, if you want that you should make it plain in the question.

Comment: There is no Tuple in .Net 3.5

Comment: I thougt that this may be another question that's why I didn't add it.
@Mario: I don't need a tuple to create my class, I just replaced it with my class taking three parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the members of your anonymous type some names.

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new { 
        Field1 = x.Field<string>("Field1"), 
        Field2 = x.Field<string>("Field2")});
```

If you think about it, no names would make it very difficult to refer to the properties later, you'd have to use reflection and some guess work. In any case, the names need to be defined so that the anonymous type can be created for you, behind the scenes.

---

If you prefer returning a `Tuple` instead of an anonymous type you can do

```
    var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => Tuple.Create( 
        Field1 = x.Field<string>("Field1"), 
        Field2 = x.Field<string>("Field2")));
```

Then you can access the members with `Item1` and `Item2` respectively.

**However**, the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class is new to .Net 4.0 and your question is tagged 3.5

---

In response to your comment, you could always declare your own type

```
public class MyPair<TItem1, TItem2>
{
    public MyPair(TItem1 item1, TItem2 item2)
    {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
    }

    public TItem1 Item1 { get; private set; }
    public TItem2 Item2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Which, obviously you would use like this,

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new MyPair( 
        Field1 = x.Field<string>("Field1"), 
        Field2 = x.Field<string>("Field2")));
```

Comment: _"you'd have to use reflection"_ and what was the name you would have use to locate the property... :)

Comment: @gdoron, yep, those names are important.

Comment: No Tuple but a replacement working the same way, needing not to name any anonymous type, like... .Select(x => new MyObject(x.Field<string>("Field_1"), x.Field<string>("Field_2"))

Answer (score 2):

You need to put names for the properties:

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Field1 = x.Field<string>("Field1"), 
        Field2 = x.Field<string>("Field2")
    });
```

And then use it:

```
var field1 = result.First().Field1;
```

The compiler doesn't know how to infer a name from something like `x.Field<string>("Field1")`. But this would work:

```
int id = 1;
string name = "Myname";
var obj = new { id, name }; // Names are inferred from the variable name.

var result = obj.name; // This would work
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says it all, give names to the members:

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new { 
                    First = x.Field<string>("Field1"),
                    Second = x.Field<string>("Field2")
                 });
```